# "Illegal reference to net " error in systemverilog - trying to design simple arbitrer

Tags: system-verilog

Here is the code I have for simple **arbitrer**

```
        module arbiter(clk,rst,req,grnt,req_val);
    input clk;
    input rst;
    input [3:0] req;
    input [3:0] req_val;
    output [3:0] grnt;

    int j;
    int i;
    parameter A = 2'd0;
    parameter B = 2'd1;
    parameter C = 2'd2;
    parameter D = 2'd3;
    logic [1:0] current_state; 
    logic [1:0] next_state;
    always_comb
    begin
    case (current_state)
        D:
        begin
            grnt = 4'b1000; 
            j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i<4;i++) begin

                if (req[(j+i) % 4 ] == 1) 
                    break;
            end
            case (i)
                0: next_state = A;
                1: next_state = B;
                2: next_state = C;
                3: next_state = D;
            endcase
        end
        A:
        begin
            j = 1;
            grnt = 4'b001; 
            for (i = 0; i<4;i++) begin
                if (req[(i+j) % 4] == 1) 
                    break;
            end
            case (i)
                0: next_state = A;
                1: next_state = B;
                2: next_state = C;
                3: next_state = D;
            endcase
        end
        B:
        begin
            j = 2;
            grnt = 4'b0010; 
            for (i = 0; i<4;i++ ) begin
                if (req[(i+j) % 4] == 1) 
                    break;

            end
            case (i)
                0: next_state = A;
                1: next_state = B;
                2: next_state = C;
                3: next_state = D;
            endcase
        end
        C:
        begin
            j = 3;
            grnt = 4'b0100; 
            for (i = 0; i<4;i++ ) begin
                if (req[(i+j)% 4] == 1) 
                    break;

            end
            case (i)
                0: next_state = A;
                1: next_state = B;
                2: next_state = C;
                3: next_state = D;
            endcase
        end
    endcase
    end
    endmodule


    always_ff@(posedge clk)
    begin
    current_state <= next_state;
    end
endmodule
```

and I get the following error:

> arbitrer.sv(21): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "grnt".

and

> arbitrer.sv(87): near "always_ff": syntax error, unexpected always_ff, expecting class.

So whats wrong with grnt ? I cant assign directly to a module output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You have used `endmodule` statement twice in your code. Just comment out one at line number 86.
2. You haven't define a data type for `grnt` variable, so by default it's a `wire` and `wire` can't be used in always block, so declare it as a `reg`/`logic`.

Comment: thnx a lot, its compiled , but it doesnt function good - it doesnt change state - can you see whats the problem?

Comment: What is the initial current state value? What is its value upon reset? This might occur since you have no reset logic in your design.